# It it possible to use javascript to save a file to same directory as current file?

Tags: javascript, html, security, webserver

I am writing JavaScript code which is executed in a local web server.
Is it possible to have that code generate another file, which is then added to the same directory as the original file? If so, how?

Comment: Please be more precise. Are you running the code clientside or serverside?

Comment: NodeJS is technically javascript and server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things have greatly changed with HTML5 and so the answer is "Yes!" provided that one is using a modern browser and/or one takes advantage of JavaScript libraries that may aid with this endeavor.  Take a look [here](https://codepen.io/davidelrizzo/pen/cxsGb) as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file/32295448#32295448).  If you alter your browser's download settings to the desired folder of your local web server, when you submit the form the file will be downloaded there.  I tried this using google chrome 49 on a windows box using wampserver and the file was saved exactly in the specified folder.  After forking the code  [here](https://codepen.io/davidelrizzo/pen/cxsGb), it ran successfully on my local webserver from the directory where I wanted the new file to be downloaded.

The pertinent jQuery code from codepen.io:

```
$("#btn-save").click( function() {
      var text = $("#textarea").val();
      var filename = $("#input-fileName").val()
      var blob = new Blob([text], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
      saveAs(blob, filename+".txt");
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't save file in same directory as current file. You have to change browser settings.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert on this, but I will try to help out. From my understanding the only way to create a file on the server is to have server side code do it. You could have the javascript call some endpoint and that could create the file. But I believe it is impossible to directly create the file.

Comment: What would an implementation of this look like? Sorry, I am new to web-based programming

Comment: I think a good place to start would be with Node.js. If you already know javascript you aren't learning a new language. There is definitely a learning curve though. I got started with [this](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/).

Comment: The structure would be: client->http.post->saves the file->returns to client a confirmation.